# RichTextField in FabricUI

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui

Hi I have been using TextField in my project. But, now I need href support in it.

e.g. if the text contains a http link it should work as a link when clicked.

similarly for hash tags and emails.

I know that TextField does not have support for that.
 Is there a workaround for this? Or should I create a feature request?

Comment: A TextField is meant to be a styled version of a browser's native `input`, which also doesn't support this use case. I'd recommend looking at a "rich text editor" that will allow for wysiwyg editing -- those should have better support for clickable links in editable text.

Comment: Feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/13561